# How do I place the return statement correctly?

Tags: python

I have a code snippet which checks a condition and returns if it(condition) turns out to be true.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import settingsTwitter
import tweepy

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    httpsCheck = 'https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'
    httpCheck = 'http?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'
    idSelf = 0
    tweet = []
    def on_status(self, status):
        print "on_status is called"
        if status.retweeted:
            return
        tweetText = status.text.encode('utf8')
        created_at = status.created_at
        id = status.id
        if (re.findall(self.httpCheck, tweetText) or re.findall(self.httpsCheck, tweetText)):
            return
        if (re.search('[a-zA-Z]', tweetText)):
            self.idSelf += 1
            self.tweet["text"] = tweetText
            self.tweet["time"] = created_at
            self.tweet["id"] = id
            self.tweet["sequence"] = self.idSelf

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            return False

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(settingsTwitter.TWITTER_APP_KEY, settingsTwitter.TWITTER_APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(settingsTwitter.TWITTER_KEY, settingsTwitter.TWITTER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
stream_listener = StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
stream.filter(languages=["en"], track=["#RCBvMI"])
```

An error is thrown for the line #19:

> File "streamTweets.py", line 19
>       return SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

```
if (re.findall(self.httpCheck, tweetText) or re.findall(self.httpsCheck, tweetText)):
            return
```

Comment: Double check all of your indentation. Make sure you are not mixing spaces and tabs. Use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: you can simply use `pass` and make the second `if` as `elif`

Comment: A small description of what you're doing would be helpful for us to debug.

Comment: @theausome I am trying to save the tweets pertaining to a certain hashtag. I do not want any tweet which: a) is simply a retweet b) contains any kind of URL

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, the error was my mixture of tabs and spaces.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If you want to post an answer, please do so. I have to accept it. It solved my problem. Thanks :)